# Trace-inequality on triangle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, finite-element-method, numerical-calculus

I need to show that for $f\in C^1(T)$ on a triangle $T$ with corner points $P$ and edges $E$ with $D=\max \{|P-x|:x\in E \}$
$$
\parallel f \parallel_{L^2(E)}^2 \leq \frac{|E|}{|T|}\parallel f \parallel_{L^2(E)} (\parallel f \parallel_{L^2(T)}^2+d\parallel \nabla f \parallel_{L^2(T)}^2)
$$
Now sadly I have no idea how to proof this but maybe one has to use the Poincare'- or Friedrich's inequality? Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: This result with an elementary proof can be found in 
Error estimates for some quasi-interpolation operators
Verfürth, Rüdiger;
ESAIM: Mathematical Modelling and Numerical Analysis; Volume 33 (1999) no. 4, p. 695-713

Comment: http://www.numdam.org/item/M2AN_1999__33_4_695_0/